# How can i connect to memcached via C sys/socket.h?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, memcached

How can i connect to Memcached via C sys/socket.h and set some text string to key "key"? I can't figure out how can I run .c program which will connect to cashing system via socket. I can connect to it through console by writing smth like this

```
memcached -l 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -m 64 -vv
```

and then

```
set key 1 0 4
test
```

but i have to do it using socket in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some knowledge regarding C sockets in general.
As an overview, a socket is a two way communication channel that connects a client with a server, each having their own end of the socket.

What memcached is doing is using the socket mechanism to transfer data between memcached and whoever it is looking for the data.

memcached is using TCP sockets and clear text messages so it is easy to work with.

What you'll have to do:

1. open a socket and connect it to the memcached server at 127.0.0.1 port 12345 (taken from your example)
2. Write 'set key 1 0 4\n' to the memcached socket
3. Read the string from the socket (this is memcached result)

The following read: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/ provides code snippets and great explanation on sockets and how to use them, and the client code contains 90% of the work you need to do

Feel free to ask if you need further clarifications